# How to get a fields particular value of JSON in Codeigniter Php?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm using Google Map Api, and getting the result in JSON form and the output result is

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Plot No 1",
               "short_name" : "Plot No 1",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "B Block Road",
               "short_name" : "B Block Rd",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Rangpuri Extention B-Block Pocket-4",
               "short_name" : "Rangpuri Extention B-Block Pocket-4",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New Delhi",
               "short_name" : "New Delhi",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "South West Delhi",
               "short_name" : "South West Delhi",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Delhi",
               "short_name" : "DL",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "110037",
               "short_name" : "110037",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Plot No 1, B Block Rd, Rangpuri Extention B-Block Pocket-4, New Delhi, Delhi 110037, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 28.5379687,
                  "lng" : 77.121816
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 28.5377897,
                  "lng" : 77.1217006
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 28.5378435,
               "lng" : 77.1217523
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 28.5392281802915,
                  "lng" : 77.12310728029151
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 28.5365302197085,
                  "lng" : 77.12040931970849
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJibjV7RYcDTkRnaFq2Lg__b4",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

and I want to extract lat and lng,under the location object, write now I'm using this code

```
$mapcontent = json_decode($content,true);
 $lat = $mapcontent['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
 $lng = $mapcontent['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```

where $content is the output result which mention above,by using the above code and it works but sometimes I'm getting error of undefined offest:0, on $lat and $lng line, is there any other way to retrieve specific data from the JSON Code, I already search on internet but I'm not getting any idea how to resolve this, please help me out

Comment: then just check the index first

Comment: I already mention , the above code is works fine, but sometimes I'm getting error of Undefined Offset:0 on $lat and $lng line, I just want some another way to retrieve data from this JSON

Comment: and I already mentioned, if that index is a hit or miss, then you should probably check index zero first, either via `array_key_exists` or probably `empty`. a simply ternary operator should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the code like :

```
$mapcontent = json_decode($content,true);
$resultCount = count($mapcontent['results']);
if( $resultCount > 0 ) {
    $lat = $mapcontent['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $lng = $mapcontent['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
}
```

It will work.

Comment: `count($mapcontent['results'][0]);` is still checking [0] and will return undefined if not found. must be `count($mapcontent['results']);`

Comment: yeah.. @JamesLalor Thanks!! It was just because of copy and paste :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$url='your url';            
$array = file_get_contents($url);
$array = (array)json_decode($array);
```

Comment: Try to add some more description or explanation to the answer. What the code do? What should the author change? How will it resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can also write code like.

```
$mapcontent = json_decode($content,true);
if( true != empty($mapcontent['results'])) {
    $lat = $mapcontent['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $lng = $mapcontent['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
}
```